# Bind navigation to fullscreen slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I am using **[fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs)** to generate a full screen sliding website.

I have four `sections` with four navigation points as `li` generated by the plugin. The first `li a` links to the `first section`, the second `li a` to the `second section`, etc.

```
section1    li a
section2    li a
section3    li a 
section4    li a
```

On click `section3` gets removed. Now I have less sections than navigation points.

```
section1    li a
section2    li a
section4    li a
            li a
```

For a reason I need the fourth `li a` still being able to be linked to `section4`.

Although I want to fire a function `restoreSection3()` when someone clicks on the `third li a`

Can someone help me on this? You can check the **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/615/)** for better understanding. Try removing `section3` and use the navigation at the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to, instead of removing the slide by toggling its `display`, removing the slide by setting its `height` to 0, and hiding its content overflow.

Like this:

```
function removeSection3() {
    // hide it by setting a height of 0, hiding overflow, and setting display to `block`
    $("#f03").css({ display:"block", height:0, overflow:"hidden"});
    silentScroll($('.fp-section.active').position().top);
}

function restoreSection3() {
    // resetting the display to `table` will make the overflow visible again
    $("#f03").css({ display:"table"});
    silentScroll($('.fp-section.active').position().top);
}
```

You can see a demo of that code working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/616/

Now when you click on the 4th link, it goes to section 4. On the down side, when you click on the 3rd link, it goes to section 4 too. So let's complete the request by adding an event listener that will trigger `restoreSection3()` when the third `li a` is clicked:

```
$("#fp-nav li:nth-child(3) a").on("click", function() {
    // we restore section 3 by simulating clicking on the "Restore Section 3" button
    $('button#first').click();
});
```

So in the end the code would look like this:

```
function removeSection3() {

    // hide it by setting a height of 0 and hiding the overflow
    $("#f03").css({ display:"block", height:0, overflow:"hidden"});

    // add an event listener, so when the third link is clicked, section 3 will be restored
    $("#fp-nav li:nth-child(3) a").on("click", function() {
        // we restore by simulating clicking on the "Restore Section 3" button
        $('button#first').click();
    });

    silentScroll($('.fp-section.active').position().top);
}

function restoreSection3() {
    // reset the display to table will make the overflow visible again
    $("#f03").css({ display:"table"});
    silentScroll($('.fp-section.active').position().top);
}
```

You can see it working on this other JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/618/

Now everything works as expected when you click on the navigation on the left, although it still may seem a bit *funky* when you use the mouse wheel: as section 3 won't be enabled, when the third and fourth links are active, section 4 will be displayed. What would be the expected behavior for this case?

Not trying to question your reasons to do things this way, but in terms of usability, it may be better to remove the third section and the third navigation link, as users may get confused if they see 4 navigation links but only 3 sections while they are scrolling.

Comment: Hey @alvaro, this is a GREAT answer! Thanks a lot for your effort. The more I am excited about a solution, the more I am thankful, that you took your time to explain it as well as you did. I am quite able to "recreate" your process. The only thing, that falls apart, is, that on a touch device (like an ipad) the third button still navigates to the fourth section. This is totally wired, and I do not know why. If you have any suggestions I appreciate this a lot! To me it seems like another script in fullpage.js overrides your command.

Comment: @MarianRick maybe you could bind the event to the `click` and `touchstart` events, like this: `$("#fp-nav li:nth-child(3) a").on("click touchstart", function() { ... })`. Try it, and let me know how it goes